# How to Remove Leading Zeros from String? Convert int to fixed-width string with leading spaces instead of zeros

Tags: assembly, x86-16, number-formatting, tasm, dosbox

I'm very VERY new to Assembly language, and I would like to know how to remove the zeros in front of an integer string? This is the last thing I needed before completing it, and here is what our professor made us modify:

```
    ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA
CODE    SEGMENT
BUFFER  DB 7 DUP (?)
DATA    SEGMENT
MYNAME  DB 'Name$'
DATA    ENDS
START   PROC
    
    MOV AX, SEG DATA
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV DX,OFFSET MYNAME
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H

    MOV DL, 10
    MOV AH, 02h
    INT 21h
    MOV DL, 13
    MOV AH, 02h
    INT 21h

    MOV AX, 65505
    CALL PRN_DEC
    MOV AX, 539
    CALL PRN_DEC
    MOV AX, 5567
    CALL PRN_DEC
    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H
START   ENDP

PRN_DEC PROC

    
    MOV BX,SEG CODE

    MOV ES,BX
    MOV DS,BX

    MOV DI, OFFSET BUFFER

    MOV BX,10000

    MOV DX,AX

    MOV CX,4

R1: MOV AX,DX
    MOV DX,0
    DIV BX  
    CMP AX,0
    JNZ R4
    MOV AX,20H
    JMP R5
R4:
    ADD AX,30H
R5: STOSB
    
    PUSH DX
    MOV AX,BX
    MOV DX,0
    MOV BX,10
    DIV BX
    MOV BX,AX
    POP DX
    LOOP R1

    MOV AX,DX
    ADD AX,30H
    STOSB   
    MOV AL,'$'
    STOSB
    
    MOV DX,OFFSET BUFFER
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H
    
    MOV DL, 10
    MOV AH, 02h
    INT 21h
    MOV DL, 13
    MOV AH, 02h
    INT 21h
    
    RET
PRN_DEC ENDP

CODE    ENDS
    END START
```

Our professor made us replace the zeros with spaces using ASCII code, but it also removed the zero in the middle of the string. I want to be able to restore it.

Comment: Stop at the first non zero then so it does not replace in the middle.

Comment: hello, i'm sorry for asking but how do i do that?

Comment: Well it looks like you are doing that during conversion so maybe keep a flag whether you have already seen a non-zero.

Comment: The string is the result of int->string conversion?  Stop looping when repeated division makes the number zero, instead of using a fixed 4 iterations (@Jester).  The `loop` instruction isn't appropriate here, just `test ax, ax` / `jnz R1` to keep looping while non-zero.  See [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45904075)

Comment: Yeah but @dsadada is doing the conversion starting with the most significant digit (dividing by 10000 first, then 1000, 100, 10) which is why the loop is fixed and the assignment says to print spaces instead of leading zeroes (as far as I understand it).

Comment: @Jester: Oh, I see.  I think you were replying to me but tagged the OP instead.  Since they want a fixed length, they could convert backwards from the end of a buffer filled with spaces initially, using the one-div-per-digit method which is simpler and more efficient in general.  They are already filling a buffer for a later print-string DOS call.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CODE    SEGMENT
> BUFFER  DB 7 DUP (?)
> DATA    SEGMENT
> MYNAME  DB 'Name$'
> DATA    ENDS
> ```

How quaint to see that BUFFER defined in the CODE segment!

> hello, i'm sorry for asking but how do i do that?

- Instead of using `mov cx, 4` to control the loop using the `loop` instruction, I first chose to detect the divisor BX becoming 1 which will happen after 4 iterations. Then I moved this detection up so I now have an early out once BX becomes 10. This avoids the silly division of 10 / 10.
- To solve the replacement issue, I start counting the non-zero digits. I use CX for that. I only allow replacement if CX is zero.

```
    xor  cx, cx    ; Counts the non-zero digits
R1: mov  ax, dx    ; Load the previous remainder
    xor  dx, dx
    div  bx
    test ax, ax    ; [0,9]
    jnz  R2
    test cx, cx
    jnz  R3        ; If CX = 1+ then it's no longer allowed to replace
    mov  al, " "
    jmp  R4
R2: inc  cx
R3: add  al, '0'
R4: stosb
    cmp  bx, 10
    je   R5

    PUSH DX
    MOV  AX, BX
    MOV  DX, 0
    MOV  BX, 10
    DIV  BX
    MOV  BX, AX
    POP  DX

    jmp R1
R5:
```

Comment: I'd have filled the buffer with `' '` initially and then converted from the end, least-significant-digit first (`*endptr-- = num % 10 + '0';  num /= 10;` as in your [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45904075)).  But yeah, if you want to show how to mostly keep the OP's algorithm, some extra branching on the quotient can do it.